# Missing faces when switching from Sculpt to Edit mode in Blender

Tags: rendering, edit-mode

When I switch from Sculpt mode to Edit mode, I run into an issue where the faces on one arm of my model are not showing. Beforehand, I had applied the mirror modifier so that I may use the hide option in sculpt mode. Thank you in advance for any help!

PS. This is the first time I am posting a question so forgive any incorrectness in my methods or if my question is foolish.

[image: Scuplt mode]

[image: Edit mode]

Comment: Are you sure the faces aren't hidden? In edit mode, hit Alt-H to see if they were hidden.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I assumed that hiding faces would hide the vertices as well. I had not known it was possible to hide only faces and keep the vertices. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to check that you don't have duplicate vertices too. Because according to the screenshot it appears there might be duplicate vertices. Go to the Tools panel, and press the "Remove Doubles" button.